# Getting 500 error with CI 2.0.x, ajax and CSRF enabled

Tags: codeigniter, jquery, codeigniter-2

I keep getting a 500 error when submitting an ajax request. If I turn off the CSRF in config then the posting works. Once I turn it on, though, then I get the 500 error again.

In config.php I have the following values set:

```
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
```

I do have jquery cookie being loaded and in my jquery file I have the following code:

```
 $('#reorder').sortable({
    opacity: '0.5',
    update: function(e, ui){
        newOrder = $( "#reorder" ).sortable('serialize');
        csrf_cookie_name = $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name')
        console.log(newOrder);
        console.log(csrf_cookie_name);
        $.ajax({
            csrf_cookie_name: $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name'),
            url: "/client/saveOrder",
            type: "POST",
            data: newOrder,
            // complete: function(){},
            success: function(feedback){
                console.log('success');
                $("#feedback").html(feedback);
                //$.jGrowl(feedback, { theme: 'success' });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

console.log of csrf_cookie_name right now is: cd660b153522bef89dc53f7f95cd6b1d so I am getting the value it seems?

And finally a really simple function in client that does the data handling. Normally I would separate some of this out into the model but I was trying to keep it simple until I got it working.

```
function saveOrder()
    {
        $items = $this->input->post('item');
        echo '<br/>Items2:' . var_dump($items);
        $total_items = count($this->input->post('item'));

        for($item = 0; $item < $total_items; $item++ )
        {

            $data = array(
                'pageid' => $items[$item],
                'rank' => $item
            );

            $this->db->where('pageid', $data['pageid']);

            $this->db->update('pages', $data);

//          echo '<br />'.$this->db->last_query();

        }
```

There's no form being used in the view. It's just an UL with a collection of LI's that I'm dragging around to sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work finally. Here's the jquery I used to make it happen:

You have to use both the name of the token and the name of the cookie and make it part of the post object. So token name = cookie name and be sure to add a & at the end.

```
$('#reorder').sortable({
        opacity: '0.5',
        update: function(e, ui){
            newOrder = 'csrf_test_name=' + $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name') + '&';
            newOrder += $( "#reorder" ).sortable('serialize');
            console.log(newOrder);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/client/saveOrder",
                type: "POST",
                data: newOrder,
                csrf_test_name: $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name'),
                // complete: function(){},
                success: function(feedback){
                    console.log('success');
                    $("#feedback").html(feedback);
                    //$.jGrowl(feedback, { theme: 'success' });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions. Both work. Check these posts - has ALL the information you need

[a-simple-solution-to-codeigniter-csrf-protection-and-ajax](http://unruhdesigns.com/blog/2012/03/a-simple-solution-to-codeigniter-csrf-protection-and-ajax)

[ajax-csrf-protection-codeigniter-2.0](http://aymsystems.com/ajax-csrf-protection-codeigniter-20)

Comment: I've been trying that. I even changed the name from csrf_cookie_name to csrf_token_name wondering if that, by chance, would make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems in the past when inadvertently using a `<form>` tag instead of using CI's native [form helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) `form_open()`.  This needs to be present in order to create the hidden token field.  There are also some good suggestions here: [csrf-token-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581494/codeigniter-csrf-token-problem).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem few days ago, the solution is simple(at least for me).
change:
`$.ajax({
            csrf_cookie_name: $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name')`
to
`$.ajax({
            csrf_test_name: $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name')`